Another proof that $0v = \boldsymbol{0}$
I'm currently a high school student reading Linear Algebra Done Wrong and one of the exercises there is to prove that $0v = \boldsymbol{0}$, where 0 is a scalar and $\boldsymbol{0}$ is the zero vector. My approach was this:
$$(1-1)v = 0v = 1v-1v = v - v = \boldsymbol{0}$$
However, I noticed that all the proofs I found online were not using this so I'm not sure if this is correct. I greatly appreciate your response!
EDIT: Thanks for the replies! so here's what I did now:
v = 1v = (1+0)v = 1v+0v = v+0v

Then we can add the additive inverse of v to get:
0 = v-v = (v+0v)-v = (0v+v)-v = 0v+(v-v) = 0v

See for a similar discussion here, doing it with $1\cdot v=(1+0)\cdot v$.

You'll need to prove first that  $(a-b)v= av-bv$ since that's not one of the axioms defining a vector space.

How are you proving that $-1v=-v?  Depending on how you prove that, your proof may be circular.

"Linear Algebra Done Wrong"? Do u mean "Linear Algebra Done Right"?

@AdamRubinson - https://www.math.brown.edu/streil/papers/LADW/LADW.html
